# Is it possible to include the site name as query parameter to MSDeploy within MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy

I am trying to setup a CI process with Team Build and VS2012. I've setup the web server to accept web deployment. I've installed Web Deploy 3.0, IIS Management Services and have configured the permissions to the website dir.

I have a msbuild project that compiles, packages and then deploys the site using MSDeploy but I'm coming across a issue that seems to be happening to many but I haven't been able to find a clear answer.

The problem stems from needing to pass in the site name to MSDeploy so that the user the build server runs under can publish. Like so:

`https://computername:8172/msdeploy.axd?site={websitenameonly}`

I've tried various ways to include this in the MSBuild file but they all end in failure. The '=' seems to break the string and cause the {websitenameonly} to be considered as another parameter.

Has anyone successfully been able to pass in the site name via MSBuild?

Answer (score 0):

The MSBuild scripts will append `?site` for you, so there's no need to do it yourself.

Make sure you've set the following in your `pubxml`:

- `MSDeployPublishMethod` is `WMSVC`
- `MsDeployServiceUrl` is in the format `https://computername:8172/msdeploy.axd`
- `DeployIisAppPath` is set to your IIS site name
- You *haven't* set `NormalizePublishSettings` to `false` (I doubt you have, but worth checking)

Comment: I've created a publish.proj file as described in http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/understanding-the-build-process by running this proj file with msbuild it does not automatically append the ?site parameter. Apparently this only works if you web deploy using VS and not via a custom build script

Comment: The way it's described in the article msbuild will output the webpackage. Then part of the publish script is to call msdeploy.exe on the cmd file generated via the package. This is where I think the problem is. Thoughts?